# Prevent debugging projects that are added as reference in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have a project that is auto generated.  This project is referenced by my web app in visual studio.  When i step through the code in debug mode the code from this project gets stepped into.  Is there a way I can skip this code in debug mode.

I can't use System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute since the code will get replaced every time my datasource changes.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should remove pdb files of the project which you don't want to debug.

A program database (PDB) file holds debugging and project state information that allows incremental linking of a Debug configuration of your program.

similar question/answer : [Can you debug a .NET app with ONLY the source code of one file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107179/can-you-debug-a-net-app-with-only-the-source-code-of-one-file)

Comment: Thanks I added 
cd $(TargetDir)
del FileName.pdb
to the post build commands to do this automatically